# Single word for "communication not intended for me"?

Tags: synonyms, technical

What does one call communication on some shared medium (phone party line, a public radio frequency, posts on a forum) that may be relevant and useful to others but not to oneself.

Context: I am doing some programming and am stumped trying to find a good short variable name. Without getting too technical, I have a device that's communicating on a "party line" and wants to count messages that are "not addressed to me". Is there a single word or two short words that concisely describe this concept? If there's a word for this in, say, German or Japanese, I think I can borrow that as well... might make the documentation more interesting.

Edit: Shifted focus of the question from the programming context to the general idea of the question. I named the variable long ago, but hopefully clarifying the question promotes more general answers.

Comment: SEP - Somebody Else's Problem - see Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy for explanation.

Comment: How about "**noise**"?

Comment: *numNotMine*...

Comment: Thank you everyone for answers, unfortunately none of the answers so far stick out as magical to me. I like "prattle" because it is the word least likely to conflict with existing terminology for something else in the system. Chatter is probably still the best thing I can think of.. so it's getting named com_chatter to distinguish it from mechanical connection chatter, the metaphor being "radio chatter" - often useful to someone but not necessarily the person listening. cont...

Comment: Noise and cross talk have mathematically specific meanings in this context that are objectively not what I am measuring here. Noise implies usually random signal fluctuations that obscure the signal, not "messages for others". As for cross talk, see my comment on the answer.

Comment: What are you calling the variables to count your messages? You could have for e.g. *myMessageCount*, *totalMessageCount* and ***otherMessageCount*** where the last one is for messages addressed to other people.

Comment: goodMessages, errorMessages, exceptionMessages. The context is Modbus communication.

Comment: Naming requests, including naming programming variables/classes, are explicitly out of scope because interest in the correct answer is extremely limited and because what counts as a correct answer is extremely subjective. Most other word requests are also out of scope for this site. The rare exception would be a request which is (1) expert-level, (2) particularly interesting, unique, and thought-provoking, and (3) showing effort and research into the question.

Comment: @MετάEd I'll try to be more careful about that rule next time. However, even in this case that claim is debatable. What I am looking for is a word that describes the concept of "communication not intended for me". I hoped some context would be helpful. Note that the technical answers are the ones I am shooting down because they are not a general term for the concept and carry very specific technical connotation, which is what I am trying to get away from. I am past trying to name a variable, and am still reading this thread because it is thought-provoking, seeing how hard it is to answer

Comment: You'll have to make something up, and it will matter what you have called your other counters. For example if you have "myMessages" then maybe "notMyMessages" or maybe "eavesdroppedMessages" or "overheardMessages". But maybe not "foreignMessages" because the word "foreign" can have a technical meaning when you are dealing with IP packets.

Comment: I like "near missive".

Answer (score 5):

**cross talk** [(Merriam-Webster)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cross%20talk)
*unwanted signals in a communication channel (as in a telephone, radio, or computer)*

I feel this is better than **noise** for OP's exact context, since it carries a much stronger implication that the unwanted signal is a *communication* intended for some other recipient, not just random [**static**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/static) (crackling or hissing noises on a telephone, radio, or other telecommunication system).

Comment: In that case you should use the definition 2A, I think. :)

Comment: Yes, definition 2A fits pretty much perfectly. However, in the electronics context pretty much everyone assumes definition 1. You left out a key part of definition 1 in the answer: "caused by transference of energy from another circuit". That is what makes is specifically cross talk and not noise or cross-channel interference or one of many other unwanted signals in a communication channel. "Cross" because it has to cross a boundary to be cross talk. What I am trying to describe is naturally present and useful to others but ignored by me.

Comment: I'm not an electronics specialist, but I've always used (and *heard*) ***crosstalk*** in two specific contexts. 1.) Degradation of stereo channel separation in hi-fi equipment (partly down to *mechanical* energy transfer in magnetic pickup cartridges, not just electromagnetic), and 2.) Other people's conversation(s) on a telephone "party line" (primarily down to the limitations of older *multiplexing* technology). I personally don't normally use it for MW-s defn 2a, which I'd probably call a ***digression*** or an ***aside***.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe **prattle**?  It doesn't imply "not addressed to you" but it does mean inconsequential verbiage.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prattle

Answer (score 1):

**Noise** — [Business Dictionary](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/noise.html)

> *communication* Anything that interferes with, slows down, or reduces the clarity or accuracy of a communication.
>
> Thus, superfluous data or words in a message are noise because they detract from its meaning.

Answer (score 0):

The action of listening in on communication is known in the computing world as **sniffing** and a device which does so is known as a packet/information **sniffer**. (See: https://www.wireshark.org/)